# How to restore deleted objects in R?

Tags: r, data-mining, statistics

Suppose if I delete all the objects from current session:

```
rm(list=ls())
```

Is there any way in base R or using a function from a package which lets me restore the deleted objects from the current session?

Comment: if some of them aren't in a workspace r data file, then no. you destroyed the in-memory copy of the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is unfortunately no. There is no handy ctrl-z method.

A tip to avoid these situations: I suggest you always save either the 'environment' or, as I prefer to do, the scripts with the codes for the desired objects, and save them regularly. I never type any commands directly into a work space, but always in a script which I save. This is so I can always look back at which steps I took in my coding.
 Personally, I save my scripts with date notations in the file name - so when I change a script I'll still have access to the old version of the scripts. It has happened quite a few times that I've changed a code and later realized that the old code was better. It's quite a hassle when you don't have the old file saved.

Answer (score 0):

Close the Window and Click Do Not Save. You will lose the work from the current session, but you will be able to recover up to the last save.